# Compare ruby array of arrays

Tags: ruby

I have this array

```
a = [[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,6],[2,8,9]]
```

How can I get the intersection of all the arrays in `a`? It should be the same as `a[0]&a[1]&a[2]`, which is:

```
[2]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
a = [[1 ,2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 6], [2, 8, 9]]

a.inject(:&)
# => [2]
```